# About taylor polynomials

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Suppose

1. f is infinitely differentiable on $R$.
2. There is L>0 such that $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq L$ for all $n\in N$.

3.$f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for $n\in N$.

Prove: $f(x)=0$ on $R$.

I started to write the expansion of $f(x)$ as:

$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!} (x-x_0)^k+R_n(x)$.

Now I can look at this with absolute value, but still it is not trivial for me.

Answer (score 1):

First we gonna show that $\forall n\geq 0:f^{(n)}(0)=0$ via strong induction:
Since $f$ is differentiable, it is also continuous and with your condition (3), we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\frac{1}{n})=f(0)=0$$ This is our base case taken care of.
Now, suppose $\forall k<n:f^{(k)}(0)=0$. Using a taylor expansion around 0, we get $$f(x)=\frac{x^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(0)+\int_{0}^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}f^{(n+1)}(t)dt$$
Plugging in $\frac{1}{m}$ for $x$ and multiplying by $n!m^n$, we get the equation $$f^{(n)}(0)=-m^n\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{m}}(\frac{1}{m}-t)^nf^{(n+1)}(t)dt$$
Taking the absolute value, using the triangle inequality for integrals and your condition (2), we get $$|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq Lm^n\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{m}}(\frac{1}{m}-t)^ndt$$
Evaluating the integral on the RHS, we get $$|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq \frac{L}{(n+1)m}$$ and with taking the limit as $m\to\infty$, it is clear that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$.
Thus, this property holds for all natural numbers.
Now, using a taylor expansion around 0 again, we get $$f(x)=\int_{0}^x\frac{(x-t)^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}f^{(2n)}(t)dt$$ and using the absolute value, triangle inequality, condition (2), evaluating the integral, we get $$|f(x)|\leq L\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ and it is well known that the RHS goes to 0 as $n\to\infty$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $f=0$.
QED

Comment: Hi $Manatee Pink tanks. I am trying to solve it without integrals, just using calculus 1 (taylor polynomial, Lagrange residue..)

Comment: Integrals aren't part of calculus 1? Weird. Even for the Lagrange residue, it is actually derived via integrals and the mean value theorem. However, using the Lagrange residue actually simplifies the proof further since you can get to the necessary inequalities without integrating. You should be able to adapt the proof easily.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you actually need integrals and the fundamental theorem of calculus for Taylor's Theorem, so I really don't understand the no integral requirement...

Comment: Hi @Manatee Pink yeah integrals is not a part of calculus 1. How csn it be done wiyhout integrating ?

Comment: @Bestmat as I have written before, use the Lagrange Residue instead of the Integral Residue. The proofs are almost the same and you should be able to adapt it without further help.